# Reference Data Type compares with Primitive Data Type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, immutability

I am a little bit confused about this topic
for example

```
var person = "Kobe";
var another = person;
```

is variable another create an another copy or just reference to person? That being said, if I change person to something else, will another also be changed??

Compare to

```
var person = {name: "Kobe"};
var another = person;
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: thx tkone for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript by reference vs. by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

Strings (also numbers and booleans) are copied on assignment in JS, object and function share references

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but as i remember strings behave a little differently `person` and `another` variable refer to same location in heap, before until they hold same value, but if you change value one of them new location in the heap is created.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the internal JS engine process, but what is important from the practical point of view is that strings get copied on assignment, no matter what happens in memory. So, if `person = "Mike"`, then `another` remains `Kobe`, and visaversa;